# How to do double 'if' statement that jumps to the same 'else' if any is false

Tags: c#, if-statement

The title might be confusing, I'm really not sure how to name my problem more properly.

Just look at the code. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is: If 'first' is false I want to go to 'else' always but if WE ARE checking for 'second' I want to go to 'else' if 'first' OR 'second' is false.

```
    //'first' and 'second' might be true, might be false

    if(first)
    {
        if(checkSecond && !second)
        {
            //If we allow checking for 'second' and 'second' is false go to else (but we can't)
        }

        if(!checkSecond)
        {
            //Do something when 'first' was true and we are not checking 'second'
            checkSecond = true; //allow checking second;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Reset when 'first' is false
        //or
        //when 'second' is false if we allow checking it (but we can't)
        checkSecond = false; //don't allow checking second;
    }
```

I figured out some syntax how it could look like if I were to implement it, it might make my problem a bit cleaner (or maybe there already exists something like that that I don't know)

```
    if (first && if (checkSecond) second) //go to else if 'first' is false OR 'second' is false if 'checkSecond' is true
    {
        if(!checkSecond)
        {
            //Do something when 'first' was true and we are not checking 'second'
            checkSecond = true; //allow checking second;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Reset when 'first' is false
        //or
        //when 'second' is false if we allow checking it
        checkSecond = false; //don't allow checking second
    }
```

Comment: you can use `||` for OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&&` for `checkSecond` with `second` to achieve this.

```
if(first && !(checkSecond && !second))
{
}
else
{
}
```

Here if `checkSecond` is `false` the seocnd part of the condition (`!(checkSecond && !second)`) is alway true. Hence, it depends just on the value of `first`. Also, if `checkSecond` is `true`, the value of the second part of the condition is depend on the value of `second`. If it is `true`, the second part is `true` and if it is `false`, the second part will be `false` (as the `checkSecond` is `true`). Thereofre, all what you want is statisfied.

Moreover, you can have the alternate form of the condition in the following:

```
if(first && (!checkSecond || second))
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: @FCin No, it's the same as `(!checkSecond || second)` For readability's sake, I would indeed suggest using `first && (!checkSecond || second)` - it just seems easier to understand than the current (edit after update: original) answer.